# Is $k$ in $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=p^k R$ fixed?

Tags: notation, modules

The following is taken from $\textit{Module Theory An Approach to Linear Algebra}$ By: T.S.Blyth

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercise 4.1.}$An $R-$module $M$ is said to be $\textit{cyclic}$ if it is generated by a singleton subset.  Let $M=Rx$ be a cyclic $R-$module.  Prove that the $R-$module $M$ and $R/\textit{Ann}_R(x)$ are $R-$isomorphic.
[Recall that $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=\{\lambda; \lambda x=0\}.$]  Dededuce that if $R$ is a principal ideal domain (i.e., a commutative integral domain in which every ideal is generated by a single subset) and if $x$ is such that $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=p^k R$ for some $p\in R$ then the only submodules of $M$ are those in the chain
$$0=p^k M\subset p^{k-1}M\subset\ldots\subset pM\subset p^0 M=M.$$

[Hint.  Use the correspondence theorem.]

Also here is the screenshot of the exercise:

[image]

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In the above exercise, the notation: $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=p^k R.$ Specifically, is the $k$ in $p^k$ fixed?  What i mean is if $p^k r\in p^kR,$ then $p^k r\in \textit{Ann}_R(x),$ and $p^krx=0.$ So say if we have $k=k_0\geq 1,$ then $p^{k_0} rx=0,$ $0=p^{k_0} M\subset p^{{k_0}-1}M\subset\ldots\subset pM\subset p^0 M=M.$ Each time I create the finite chain of subsets, I have to first settle  on a particular value of $k$ where $p^kr\in p^kR?$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Its $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x) = \{\lambda \in R : \lambda x = 0\}$, not $R / \operatorname{Ann}_R(x) = \{\lambda \in R : \lambda x = 0\}$.

Comment: @Tzimmo thank you for pointing that out.  Can i ask if the $k$ in $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=p^k R$ is fixed or not beforehand?

Comment: You are hypothesizing that "$x$ is such that $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=p^k R$", so at that point it is some fixed value.  In a PID it isn't even possible for $p^kR=p^jR$ for different values of $i,j$ unless $p$ is a unit or zero.

Comment: @rschwieb I am still confused, from the definition of $\textit{Ann}_R(x),$ and $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=p^k R,$ elements in $p^kR$ look like $p^kr$ for some fixed $k,$ implying that $p^krx=0$?  Is that correct?

Comment: Are you assuming $p$ is a prime element?  If not, we have to worry about the $k$, but if so, $k$ is fixed already when $p\neq 0$ and doesn't matter when $p=0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I added a screenshot of the exercise.  I hope that clears up any potential confusion to the wording of the exercise.  I am not really sure if $p$ is suppos to be prime and how that affect whether $k$ is suppose to be assumed fixed beforehand.

Comment: In short, if $p\neq 0$ need not be prime, we can choose $k$ such that the assumptions hold.  Then replace $p$ with $p^k$, essentially setting $k=1$ and tearing up the chain of modules.

Comment: @BrianMoehring elements of $p^kR$ is of the form $p^kr$, where $p, p^k, r\in R?$

Comment: @BrianMoehring also for $R/\text{Ann }_R(x)$ is of the form $r+p^kr\in r+\text{Ann }_R(x)$?

Comment: Yes and no, respectively, but what is your point?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I just want to make sure I am understanding the notations correctly.  Can I ask which ones I got correct?  Is it elements of $p^kR$ or $R/\text{Ann }_R(x)?$  If I don't get the notations correctly, I can't give correct construction of the isomorphic map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that if $p$ is a prime element of a PID, and $I=(p^k)=p^kR$, then the only $R$ submodules of $R/I$ are just $(p^iR)/I$ for $0\leq i\leq k$.

Comment: I am to interpret $p^kR$ as an ideal and hence $p^kr$  gets absorbed into $I$?

Comment: In a commutative ring with identity, yes the ideal generated by $x$ is denoted by $(x)$ or $xR$.  This is a fundamental piece of notation. I wouldn't say $p^kr$ 'gets absorbed' into $I$, i would say it _is an element of $I$_ since $I=p^kR$.

Comment: ah kk. Thank you.  The reason I ask is when i see the notion of quotient modules, I am not sure i should treat it as a quotient ring or a quotient group.  The elements for either one are written differently.  I just want to make certain.